# Azure AD Multi-Tenant Sign In - with tenants in microsoftonline.com and microsoftonline.de

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an existing web app that we will be adding Azure AD sign in for. The application is multi-tenanted and users currently sign on using our username and password system. The tenants we have may be using an Azure global account or an Azure Germany account. Since Microsoft Azure services for Azure AD are not dependent on a specific region I didn't think this would be an issue (see security + identity section [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/services/)).

To begin with I have been looking over the documentation and following the Azure samples for multi-tenanted web apps [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect). The sample app is the base of my initial trial to see how all of this works and how it can then be put into our own system.

So, my sample Azure app is registered on the global version of Azure. The sign up process is successful for a test tenant on the global site. The problem comes from the Germany test tenant.

The app directs the user to the Germany login endpoint and prompts for consent as expected. The application sitting in the global Azure is then also copied into the Germany tenant's Enterprise Application area (you can see it click on it to see the information and publisher - which actually says "Foreign Cloud Applications"). So that seems to have worked out ok also. But, upon requesting a token using AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode the following error is returned:

```
AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. 
AADSTS50012: Invalid client secret is provided.
```

I have tried generating different keys to use in AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode but the get the same result.

If anyone has figured this out before (perhaps it is not possible??), has any ideas, or could point me in the right direction of documentation or samples it would be much appreciated!

**Update:**
The fact that AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode and the Graph API does not work does not hinder logging in once consent is granted. If it is replaced with an authentication challenge the authentication ticket does come through.

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext( ).Authentication.Challenge( new AuthenticationProperties { 
            RedirectUri = "/OnBoarding/Step2?state=" + myTenant.IssValue 
        }, myTenant.IsDe ? "AzureGermany" : "AzureGlobal" );
```

And in /Onboarding/Step2 it becomes possible to find out the tenant Id through the claims principal instead of the AuthenticationResult.

```
string tenantId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid" ).Value;
```

vs

```
var result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode( code, new Uri( Request.Url.GetLeftPart( UriPartial.Path ) ), credential );
string tenantId = result.TenantId;
```

Not sure how legit it is to bypass using the Graph API with AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode to get the tenant Id and finish up the onboard process though....

Comment: The invalid client secret error you see might be related to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims/issues/19).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OAuth context, the web application is a confidential client because it authenticates with the Azure AD using a client secret. Currently, it is not possible for a confidential client application to authenticate with the German instance of Azure AD using a key generated on the global Azure portal.

If your web application needs to acquire a token on behalf of a German user account to access an API or needs to validate the token, you will have to register it separately on the [German Azure portal](https://portal.microsoftazure.de).